# Why is jboss marshalling river jar reported as missing by gwt devmode even though it is included in the classpath

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt, classpath, gwt-dev-mode

I want to run the puregwt-showcase project from geomajas in debug mode. I have checked the debug configuration and my maven dependencies are included. (should there by any particular order here?).In my maven dependencies i have this jar boss-marshalling-river-1.3.6.GA.jar included. So naturally if it is in my maven deps and my maven deps are on the debug confing claspath it should be detected right?...this is the stacktrace returned http://pastebin.com/xdkwLGkX . I have also asked on majas dev mailing list but nobody answered plus this seems more like a gwt and spring issue so i'm trying my luck here

Hoping to get so answers, or at least some leads,
Otis

EDIT: Another issue i have is that after i run gwt devmode another error pops up in my source: Template file CaptionImpl.ui.xml is missing (expected at org/geomajas/puregwt/example/client/widget/ShowcaseDialogBox) . This only appears if i run the gwt in devmode. If i try a maven install and run there are no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You server-side classes and dependencies have to be in your war folder's WEB-INF to be picked up.

As you're using Maven, you first have to `mvn package` your app to move all dependencies to `target`, and then run DevMode with the proper war directory; see https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven

Comment: I have all my dependencies in /geomajas-puregwt-showcase/target/geomajas-puregwt-showcase-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib actually. And i tried  DevMode both  ewith the default path for output source and with the modifications at  point #5. Not working